# Segue which double the view, swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I get the shops around me with the Foursquare API. I would like to get the data of the selected row to use in the other ViewController.

For instance, when I selected a row, a first upload view appeared empty ( for the first selection) or with the date of the last selection, and instantly another uploadView appeared with the data of the row selected ( The right one). When i want to came back to the TableView, I have to tap two times on the "< **Shop**" (I go through the two upload view, and the data of the Uploadview, which is between the tableview and the upload view with the good data, is still composed with the wrong data.

Do you know how to avoid this duplication of UploadView?

[Row 1 selected, upload view of the middle, composed with the data of my past selection, row 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dzb2.png)
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gviu6.png)

In the table view :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

var locationManager:CLLocationManager?;

var lastLocation:CLLocation?;

var venues:[Venue]?;

var FirstsendSelectedData = NSString()
var SecondsendSelectedData = NSString()
var ThirdsendSelectedData = NSString()
var FourthsendSelectedData = NSString()

let distanceSpan:Double = 1000; //500

var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered = [Venue]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.tableView!.delegate = self
    self.tableView!.dataSource = self
    self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 100


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("onVenuesUpdated:"), name: API.notifications.venuesUpdated, object: nil);

}

func refreshVenues(location: CLLocation?, getDataFromFoursquare:Bool = false)
{
    if location != nil
    {
        lastLocation = location;
    }

    if let location = lastLocation
    {
        if getDataFromFoursquare == true
        {
            CoffeeAPI.sharedInstance.getCoffeeShopsWithLocation(location);
        }

        let (start, stop) = calculateCoordinatesWithRegion(location);

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude < %f AND latitude > %f AND longitude > %f AND longitude < %f", start.latitude, stop.latitude, start.longitude, stop.longitude);

        let realm = try! Realm();

        venues = realm.objects(Venue).filter(predicate).sort {
            location.distanceFromLocation($0.coordinate) > location.distanceFromLocation($1.coordinate);
        }

        tableView?.reloadData();
    }
} 

func calculateCoordinatesWithRegion(location:CLLocation) -> (CLLocationCoordinate2D, CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, distanceSpan, distanceSpan);

    var start:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D();
    var stop:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D();

    start.latitude  = region.center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
    start.longitude = region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
    stop.latitude   = region.center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
    stop.longitude  = region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);

    return (start, stop);
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    if let tableView = self.tableView
    {
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
    }
}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    if locationManager == nil
    {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager();

        locationManager!.delegate = self;
        locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
        locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization();  //Pop-ups turn on geo-location
        locationManager!.distanceFilter = 50; // Don't send location updates with a distance smaller than 50 meters between them
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation();
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation)
{
    if let tableView = self.tableView
    {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, distanceSpan, distanceSpan);

        refreshVenues(newLocation, getDataFromFoursquare: true)
    }
}

func onVenuesUpdated(notification:NSNotification)
{
    refreshVenues(nil)
}
```

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return venues?.count ?? 0
    }

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BusinessTableViewCell") as? BusinessTableViewCell

    let venue = venues?[indexPath.row]

    cell!.TextLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(venue!.name)"
    cell!.DetailTextLabel?.text = venue!.address;
    cell!.longTextLabel?.text = String(venue!.longitude);
    cell!.latTextLabel?.text = String(venue!.latitude);

    print(venue!.name , venue!.address, venue!.latitude, venue!.longitude)

let distance = venue!.coordinate.distanceFromLocation((self.lastLocation)!)
cell!.distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f mi", distance / 1609.344)
cell!.distanceLabel.sizeToFit()

    print(distance)

cell!.layoutIfNeeded()

return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Get Cell Label text here and storing it to the variable
    let indexPathVal: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    print("\(indexPathVal)")
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathVal) as! BusinessTableViewCell;
    print("\(currentCell)")
    print("\(currentCell.TextLabel?.text!)")
    print("\(currentCell.DetailTextLabel?.text!)")
    print("\(currentCell.longTextLabel?.text!)")
    print("\(currentCell.latTextLabel?.text!)")
    //Storing the data to a string from the selected cell
    FirstsendSelectedData = (currentCell.TextLabel?.text)!
    SecondsendSelectedData = (currentCell.DetailTextLabel?.text)!
    ThirdsendSelectedData = (currentCell.longTextLabel?.text)!
    FourthsendSelectedData = (currentCell.latTextLabel?.text)!

    print(FirstsendSelectedData)
    print(SecondsendSelectedData)
    print(ThirdsendSelectedData)
    print(FourthsendSelectedData)
    //Now here I am performing the segue action after cell selection to the other view controller by using the segue Identifier Name
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Upload", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //Here i am checking the Segue and Saving the data to an array on the next view Controller also sending it to the next view Controller
    if segue.identifier == "Upload"{
        //Creating an object of the second View controller
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! UploadViewController
        //Sending the data here

        controller.FirstArray = FirstsendSelectedData as String
        controller.SecondArray = SecondsendSelectedData as String
        controller.ThirdArray = ThirdsendSelectedData as String
        controller.FourthArray = FourthsendSelectedData as String
    }
  }  
}
```

and in my UploadViewController:

```
class UploadViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // outlet 
    @IBOutlet weak var TextLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DetailTextLabel : UILabel!

     var FirstArray:String!
     var SecondArray:String!
     var ThirdArray:String!
     var FourthArray:String!


    // MARK: - View functions


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         TextLabel?.text = FirstArray!
         DetailTextLabel?.text = SecondArray!
         print ( ThirdArray, FourthArray)
  }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have segue the tableview cell to your next view in storyboard and put another performSegueWithIdentifier in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. You need to create the segue from your view controller to next view controller instead of from the tableview cell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the post to add the entirely code. Could you please illustrate your answer? I am a kind lost.. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Okay thank you,finally I get It!

Comment: ```override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Upload", let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? UploadViewController {
            if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
                
                var affiliation = venues?[indexPath.row]
                destination.affiliation = affiliation
            }
        }
    }
```